# Seeking ArcGIS *.tpk maps to buy / download?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, data, arcgis-api-wpf, tile-package

I have an ArcGIS for WPF application capable of displaying both online (ESRI map server) and local (*.tpk files) basemaps.  I currently have a need to be able to load a basemap of China on a machine that has no internet / network connection.

My initial thought was to find / purchase / generate a tpk file (or similar) that can be copied onto the drive of the machine in question, but I am having trouble finding such a thing.

Are basemaps available as tiled packages that can be accessed in such a manner?

I am aware that they can be rather large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go two ways.

1. Use GP tool [Create Map Tile Package (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000017w000000) (when you have a map document with vector data you want to rasterize and store within a tile package file). If you don't have vector data, consider taking a look at [Data and Maps for ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/data/data-maps/data-and-maps-dvd).
2. Use GP tool [Export Tile Cache (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000187000000) (when you have a GIS service map cache dataset and want to convert it to the tile package). The Esri basemaps are available for purchase as [Data and Maps for Server](http://www.esri.com/data/data-maps/data-and-maps-server) - you'll get the cache dataset which you can convert to tile package. **Caveat**: check whether this operation is licensed; keep in mind that you don't get into [larger scales](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/data-maps-server/10.1/index.html#/World_Street_Map/00v900000009000000/) in this cache dataset).

PS. Helpful tip for enabling [ArcGIS Runtime sharing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_to_create_a_tile_package/00660000045m000000/) in ArcMap and more general information on [tile packages and Runtime content](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_creating_Runtime_content/00660000045q000000/).

Comment: Thanks for the info - I currently don't have a licenced copy of ArcMap or the ability to use it properly, hence my hope that these things could be bought 'off the shelf' or as a paid for service.  I will follow your links however as perhaps I can generate enough to prove the concept with a trial version.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you need a [Data Appliance for ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/data-appliance)

'Data Appliance for ArcGIS is a turnkey solution that provides terabytes of worldwide basemaps and reference layers preloaded onto a network-attached storage device that plugs right into your organization's internal network.'

Comment: Thanks - I only actually need about 1000 square miles of China down to street level (ish) and no references layers so I think that might be a bit pricey!